# Figma, Auto Page Layout

Tags: layout, figma, lokalise

what is the best solution while working in Figma using auto layout and localization, what is the expected action within the frame when text is translated into different languages, what is best practice here from a Lokalise stand point and working in design

I just tried not naming the group name of an auto-layout and the plugin still used the auto-layout name. When removing a group name, Figma seems to keep “Group” by default instead of allowing it to be an empty title.